# mySQL - need help creating a query that references several tables in different ways

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with creating a query to fetch data from several tables.

These are the tables:-

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to query the base table, along with the others, to end up with these rows:-

[image]

So, the base table **make_ID** value needs to reference the **makes** table to populate the **make** column in the results. This bit I've managed to do with this query:-

```
SELECT code, make, Model_ID, time
FROM makes
INNER JOIN base
ON makes.ID = base.make_ID;
```

But the **model** column I'm finding tricky, as I need to get the result from **make**, and use that to choose the right table to get the model. So, looking at the first row, I would need to take the **make** result, which is **brillo**, and then use this to reference the **brillo** table using the id from **model_ID**, to get **finepad**.

How can I expand my query to do this? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to change the schema of this database at all? The reason that I ask, is what you would probably need is a `make_model` table which assigns Unique Identifiers for each of the makes, which then makes grabbing the subsequent models a lot easier.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @jerry M. Thanks for the comment. Is the 'makes' table not the same as your suggestion?

Comment: @MichaePavlosMichael I don't think so. Take for example `ID 1` in `Makes`, which should correspond to `brillo`. That ID ALSO appears in the tables `brillo`, `colgate`, and `mccaine`. So that doesn't allow to specifically grab exclusively brillo products. There are ways around this, but fundamentally, your database should be changed. I'd be happy to post that as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @JerryM. Right, I think I understand. So if I changed `ID` in `makes` to something unique, like `makes_ID` ( and do the same for the 3 tables containing the models ), would that be going in the right direction? If so, can you elaborate on how to tweak my query to accommodate that?

Comment: @MichaePavlosMichael yes it would. So if `makes_ID` had values A, B, and C, and the values in brillo were all A, and colgate all B, and mccaine all C, that could work.

Comment: @JerryM. So your method would allow me to keep the 3 makes (brillo, colgate and mccaine ) in their own tables, correct? Could you please show me what one of these tables might look like - and the query modification I would use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as Jerry said you need a table `make_models` like this

```
+---------------+---------+----------+------------+
| make_model_id | make_id | model_id |   model    |
+---------------+---------+----------+------------+
|             1 |       1 |        1 | finepad    |
|             2 |       1 |        2 | harshpad   |
|             3 |       2 |        1 | toothbrush |
|             4 |       2 |        2 | toothpaste |
|             5 |       3 |        1 | ovenchips  |
|             6 |       3 |        2 | porkpie    |
+---------------+---------+----------+------------+
    ^^ unique identifier
```

So in your `base` table instead of referencing `model_id` you can reference `make_model_id` which is unique so you can do your join the same way you did with `makes` table

```
SELECT code, make, Model_ID, time
FROM makes
INNER JOIN base
ON makes.ID = base.make_ID
INNER JOIN make_models
   ON base.make_id = make_models.make_id
  AND base.model_id = make_models.model_id;
```

OR:

```
INNER JOIN make_models
   ON base.make_models_id = make_models.make_models_id ;
```

If you can't change your model you can create a subquery to build it on the fly. See how I assign the `make_id` based on id from the `makes` table

```
SELECT base.code, makes.make, make_models.model, base.time
FROM base
JOIN make
  ON base.make_id = makes.id
JOIN ( SELECT 1 as make_id, model_id,  model
       FROM brillo
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 2 as make_id, model_id,  model
       FROM colgate
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 3 as make_id, model_id,  model
       FROM mccaine
     ) as make_models
  ON base.make_id = make_models.make_id
 AND base.model_id = make_models.model_id
```

Comment: I wanted to try and avoid having a single table for `makes` and `models`. This dataset is quite small, but I wanted a system that might handle hundreds of makes, each with hundreds of models. Part of the challenge set to me was to group each makes models in separate tables.

Comment: I suggest you dont create multiple tables, instead put eveything together in `make_models` as show here

Comment: I understand. I guess I will fall back to your method if I can't figure another way. I appreciate your input.